# Trying to compare String values, but seems to be converting text

Tags: java, string

My xml has text inside an element that looks like:

```
<node>#&lt;abc123&gt;</node>
```

So in my junit test I am doing an assertEqual it fails because the value I get from the xml looks like:

```
<#abc123>
```

Does calling toString on a Object decode it? Or going from a StringBuffer to a String?

Comment: How are you getting the sting from the node element?  That is probably where the conversion happens.

Comment: XML is actually an abstract data model, not a file format, and you use an XML parser to serialize it to a file. When you have the string `<#abc123>` in the data model, the parser serializes that to `&lt;#abc123&gt;` in the serialized output. And conversely, when it's parsed back in again, it's deserialized back to `<#abc123>`. They are not different strings, just different representations of the same data. It's an error to think of them as different strings. They are just at different levels of abstract representation.

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing an assert on the raw XMl string `#&lt;abc123&gt;` it is going to fail, because the following sequences are XML specific encodings that get translated away by your parser:

- &lt ; - this is an encoding for the '<' character
- &gt ; - this is an encoding for the '>' character

The reason for the encodings in the first place is pretty obvious - the '<' and '>' characters have special meaning in XML, so to include them literally in your document would cause problems for the parser.

What you need to do is assert on the String that would be outputted by your XML parser, which is `'<#abc123>'`.

Answer (score 0):

this might help you,

look for `escapeHtml` in

```
StringEscapeUtils
```

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html

Comment: XML and HTML use slightly different encoding rules. It's a bad idea to mix them.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the implementation of the toString method. toString gives a string representation of the object, in your case it converts `&lt;` to <.

Answer (score 0):

my guess would be that your xml framework unescapes the text in the moment you call getText() on the node. Maybe you have access the node content in a different way to get the raw content.